# Взаймодействие между двумя образами VMware

Tags: vmware

**Intro** Я програмист. Набор админских знаний ниже среднего. Для того чтоб не засорять хост, использую виртуалки.

Ситуация такая  - все больше использую в своих приложений БД и для того чтоб их не засорять, сделал отдельный образ для БД. Но беда - образ с средой програмирования не видит образ с БД. Можете подсказать как исправить сие досаду?Оба образа одинаковы и созданы с использованием дефолтных конфигов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте настроить, как тут написано: [настройка локальной сети между виртуальными машинами VMWare и хостом](http://delphiec.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/настройка-локальной-сети-между-вирту/).

Мне помогло - надо было поставить на виртуальной машине SQL базу, чтобы работать с ней.

Answer (score 1):

с VMware Workstation идёт тулза Virtual Network Editor. В ней можно настроить правила сетевых карт и маршрутизации для виртуальных машинок.